# Why does the cursed crew need the blood of Turner in order to lift the curse?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, the-curse-of-the-black-pearl

In *Pirates of Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl*, why does the cursed crew need the blood of a **Turner** in order to lift the curse?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to putting all of the coins back, the blood must be "repaid" for the curse to be broken. Precisely what that means is unclear, but it sounds as though the cursed person must actually die.

Since "Bootstrap" Bill Turner was one of the crew who stole the treasure, they need his blood.

Let's look at the rest of the conversation you referenced. From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean.html):

> WILL
>   What happened to William Turner?
>
> PINTEL
>   Ah, William Turner. Stupid blighter. **He threw in with us after we relieved Jack Sparrow of his captaincy, but turned out, it never sat well with him-particularly after we found Cortes', and its peculiar condition.** He thought we deserved to be cursed, for leaving ol' Jack to the fate we did. That's why he sent off a piece of the treasure -- to you, as it were: so it would never be recovered, and so cursed we remain.
>
> WILL
>   And then he ran. And he's hiding out someplace where you haven't been able to find him.
>
> PINTEL
>   That's a nice thought, to be sure, and I wager your da wishes he'd thought it hisself. But, no. See, what he'd done, didn't sit too well with Captain Barbossa ... so he chained a cannon to his legs and dumped him over.
>
> Will reacts with shock at the account of his father's fate.
>
> PINTEL (CONT'D)
>   Yep, last I saw of Bootstrap Bill, was his face looking up, as he sank down to the crushing black oblivion of Davy Jones' locker. (sighs) It was only after, we found out we needed his blood to solve the curse. That's what you call ironic.

They believe that they may not need Bill Turner specifically, and that his offspring's blood would do.

Barbossa explains this to Elizabeth, who he believes is Bill Turner's daughter at the time.

> There is but one way to remove the curse. **All of the scattered pieces of the treasure must be restored in full, and the blood repaid.**
>
> (he throws the pages aside)
>
> We've recovered every piece -- save for this.
>
> (holds up the medallion)
>
> And as for the blood ... that's what we have you for.
>
> (pleasant, finally getting to his point)
>
> And that's why there's no sense in killing you. Yet.

Comment: I still don't understand why specifically they need one of the TURNERS blood ?

Comment: Because Bootstrap Bill Turner was one of the crew who stole the coins.

Comment: no he wasn't.Quote from the script: "ELIZABETH
          That's all very interesting, but I
          hardly believe in ghost stories
          any more.

Barbossa is angry. He stands, sweeps the food off the
table.

                    BARBOSSA
          You idiot girl! It's no make-
          believe! My crew and I, we found
          the gold, and we did more than
          take one piece, we took it all.
          Rich men we were and we spent it
          and traded it and gave it away in
          exchange"

Comment: Yes, and Bill was *part of that crew*.

Comment: @Leth - in your question you included a picture from the scene where they explain that Bill was on the crew, helped steal the coins, and then turned on the crew by hiding one of the coins.  What about that was unclear?  Everyone that stole needs to repay in blood.  That's why they need a Turner.  That's what that scene was *about*.

Comment: more importantly, is bill turner just forever undead in the depths of the sea? I mean before the sequel which has him as a crew on the flying dutchman

Comment: @KaiQing - He would've been, yeah, up until Davy Jones found him and offered a deal to get out of it, or until the curse ended and let him drown and die.

Comment: @phantom42 Someone else can ask this question: How were the cursed Pirates, who had no blood after they were cursed, supposed to repay the curse with blood they no longer had?

Comment: @MajorStackings, did you ask that question?

Answer (score 1):

The coins cursed them because of their greed.

Barbossa says that they traded them for goods, Bootstrap was the only to give a coin away without anything in return (he sent it to Will).

Hence why I believe it was his blood they need, also you could say Jacks blood was needed (Which we saw him cut himself) because he also threw a coin to Will with not getting anything in return.