# Why didn't they need Jack's blood also?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, the-curse-of-the-black-pearl

Addition to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127230/why-does-the-cursed-crew-need-the-blood-of-turner-in-order-to-lift-the-curse) question, since Jack is also stole one of the pieces of the treasure, why didn't they need the blood of Jack to lift to curse ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer by just watching the movie carefully again.Actually, indeed, before throwing the last piece of the treasure, Jack cuts it own hand while holding the Aztec medallion, so indeed Jack's blood is used while lifting the curse.

[image]

Comment: Also referenced in the WIkia at http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Curse_of_the_Aztec_Gold

Comment: You must have been asleep.  They did a cut and focused on this act before cutting to will to show his reaction to the act, then carried on with him throwing the coin.  They did everything short of him saying, "Ouch!" or something to draw attention to the bloodletting.